# JPA: can't make OrderBy work

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to print ordered list after persisting it and retrieving.

My Entities:

```
@Entity
public class News {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("likes DESC")
    private List<Comment> comments = new LinkedList<>();

    //------------------
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    private int likes;
}
```

Main method snippet:

```
tx.begin();
{
    // persist
    News n1 = new News("Super news!!");
    Comment c1 = new Comment("comment 1", 1);
    Comment c2 = new Comment("comment 2", 200);
    Comment c3 = new Comment("comment 3", 10);

    n1.addComment(c1);
    n1.addComment(c2);
    n1.addComment(c3);

    em.persist(n1);

    // find
    News news = em.find(News.class, n1.getId());
    for (int i = 0; i < news.getComments().size(); i++) {
        System.err.println(news.getComments().get(i).getLikes());
    }
}
tx.commit();
```

The result printed in declaration order (1 -> 200 -> 10) and I expect (200 -> 10 -> 1).
Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are getting your entity from the entity manager and not from db, so you are getting the same object that you created (not sorted object). You should try to refresh caché before the `em.find()` method:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(n1);
em.getTransaction().commit();

// Clear object
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(News.class, n1.getId());

// find
News news = em.find(News.class, n1.getId());
for (int i=0; i<news.getComments().size(); i++){
    System.err.println(news.getComments().get(i).getLikes());
}
```

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html), the method:

```
<T> T find(java.lang.Class<T> entityClass, java.lang.Object primaryKey)
```

> Find by primary key. Search for an entity of the specified class and
>   primary key. **If the entity instance is contained in the persistence
>   context, it is returned from there**.

I empathize the part that maybe is getting you troubles.

Comment: It works! But in some strange way. I should close not only EntityManager but although EntityManagerFactory to see the descent order in output.

Comment: I edit the code to not close the entity manager and only refresh the cache for the `n1` object, maybe that should work.

Comment: You do NOT have to close anything ... just evict objects from the L1 AND L2 caches! then you get nothing from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

`@OrderBy` is applied when sql query is executed. In your case the data is already in memory so sql query is not executed. You can try using `@Sort` annotation that apply sorting in memory. Depending on your use case it may not be efficient if your list is big.

```
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = CommentsComparator.class)
```

EDIT: @Sort is a hibernate specific annotation. For pure JPA I think the collection (List) can be updated to some sorted collection like SortedSet if possible.

Comment: is he using Hibernate? because without that he really would struggle to use a HIbernate annotation

Comment: @NeilStockton: Yes, you are correct. 'Sort' is a hibernate notation and if OP is not using hibernate or do not want to use hibernate specific annotation then this will not solve problem.